# Django Form FileField/ImageField how to clear it?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a Django ModelForm connected to a Django Model with an ImageField:

```
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='athletes/', blank=True, default='')
```

This is the way I am setting up my form:

```
def get_form(info, **input):
    pk = input.pop("id", None)
    form_kwargs = {}
    if pk:
        instance = Person.objects.get(pk=pk)
        form_kwargs["instance"] = instance
    print(input)
    return PersonForm(input, info.context.FILES, **form_kwargs)
```

This is the output of the print:

```
{
 'name': 'John Doe',
 'photo': None,
 'discipline': 'Triathlon'
}
```

I am trying to update an existing model by clearing the photo attribute. I have tried setting `photo` to `None` or to empty string `''` but nothing clears the photo. Replacing the photo with another one works. As far as I understand, because "photo" is an ImageField, it can only be set from the files argument (second argument in the form). How can I clear a File/ImageField field from the form?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change model to

```
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='athletes/', blank=True, default='', null=True)
```

then you can set it to None.